# Laravel - How to display create button based created_at for current Year

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel-5.8 I have this code in the controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $userCompany    = Auth::user()->company_id;
    $userId         = Auth::user()->id;

    $currentStatus = HrLeaveRequest::select('leave_status')
        ->where('employee_id', $userId)
        ->where('is_resumption_activated', 1)
        ->whereIn('leave_status', array(3, 4))
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
        ->first();
    return view('leave.index')
        ->with('currentStatus', $currentStatus);
}
```

View blade:

```
@if ($currentstatus)
    <div style="margin-bottom: 10px;" class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <a class="btn btn-info" href="{{ route("leave.create") }}">
                Create Leave
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
@elseif (! $currentstatus)
    <div style="margin-bottom: 10px;" class="row">
    </div>
@endif
```

From the code above I want "Create Leave" to only be displayed where:

```
(
employee_id= $userId,
is_resumption_activated=1,
whereIn(leave_status,array(3,4)
)

OR

(
employee_id= $userId,
whereIn(leave_status,array(3,4), 
whereYear('created_at',date('Y'))
)
```

How do I combine these two queries separated by `OR` in `$currentStatus` and everything enclosed in `orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->first()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below code

In the controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $currentStatus = HrLeaveRequest::select('leave_status')
        ->where('employee_id', Auth::id())
        ->where(function($query) {
            $query->where('is_resumption_activated', true)
                ->orWhereYear('created_at', now()->year);
        })
        ->whereIn('leave_status', [3, 4])
        ->orderByDesc('created_at')
        ->first();

    return view('leave.index', compact('currentStatus');
}
```

And in your view :

```
@if ($currentStatus)
    <div style="margin-bottom: 10px;" class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <a class="btn btn-info" href="{{ route('leave.create') }}">
                Create Leave
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
@else
    <div style="margin-bottom: 10px;" class="row">

    </div>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#logical-grouping), you can get the desired result by running the below query.

```
$currentStatus = HrLeaveRequest::where('employee_id', $userId)
        ->whereIn('leave_status', array(3, 4))
        ->where(function($query){
          $query->where('is_resumption_activated', 1)
                ->whereYear('created_at',date('Y'))
        })
        ->exists();
```

In the above, query I have used `exists()` rather than `first()` which check if the record exist and then you dont need `orderBy`. Please check [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#determining-if-records-exist).

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can try this :

```
   public function index()
{
    $userCompany    = Auth::user()->company_id;
    $userId         = Auth::user()->id;

    $currentStatus = HrLeaveRequest::select('*')
        ->where('employee_id', $userId)
        ->first();
    return view('leave.index')
        ->with('currentStatus', $currentStatus);
}
```

And in your view :

```
@if ($currentstatus)
     @if ($currentstatus->leave_status=3 || $currentstatus->leave_status=4)
        @if($currentstatus->is_resumption_activated=1)
            <div style="margin-bottom: 10px;" class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <a class="btn btn-info" href="{{ route("leave.create") }}">
                        Create Leave
                    </a>
              </div>
           </div>
         @endif
         @if(date('Y',$currentstatus->created_at) == date('Y'))
            <div style="margin-bottom: 10px;" class="row">
            </div>
        @endif
@endif
```